# Почему в режиме active текст <button> кнопки двигается в internet explorer 11?

Tags: html, css

Почему в режиме active текст button кнопки двигается в internet explorer 11?

```css
a, a:active, 
a:focus, 
a:hover, 
button, 
button:active, 
button:focus, 
button:hover, 
input, 
input:active, 
input:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="card__one__btn">Заказать розу</button>
```

Comment: Такое поведение испокон веков было. Просто стандартный элемент так работает.

Comment: Вот тут говорят что нулевой паддинг помогает - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908309/how-to-prevent-button-text-movement-when-button-is-active-in-firefox

Comment: У меня padding: 0px; не может работать, потому что width, height не написал, а дал в верху padding: 6px 11px; .